# Autodesk Forge Data management api - get share link

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

Using the forge data management api is it possible to retrieve a share link for a file? Manually you would retrieve this by first clicking 'Share Link'

[image]

Then using the public link highlighted below

[image]

Comment: There is no way to retrieve through API a share link generated in the UI, you have to implement that kind of feature yourself on top of the API as Jaime mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement features in your web app that would allow you to generate permanent or temporary share links (private - which require login to your webapp or public), so you can send a link to a specific design to a customer.

This kind of feature could be handled by your own server/database logic that map a url to a specific design URN.

There are plenty of JS libraries that can hash the url to make it similar to the one you can use from A360.