# How to programmatically get a Shared Link for end-user access to Fusion Team items?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

Using the Data Management API for use with Fusion Team, we have successfully done the following via .NET:

1. Retrieved the necessary 3-legged authorization token.
2. Created storage in Fusion Team.
3. Uploaded files to the storage.
4. Create corresponding items for those files.

What we need at this point is a programmatic way to retrieve a shared link.

If we go through the online UI, the Share feature can create a shared link that can be used to share the item with anyone (without the need for any authorization at that point).

[![Text]()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdnCV.png)

**Is there any programmatic access to the Share mechanism from the Data Management API, or one of the other available API's?**

If there is no available API support for generating Shared Links, can a Shared Link be pieced together from available information such as Project ID, Folder ID, Item ID, and so forth?

Utilizing the resultant Shared Link (generated from the online UI) into a browser, we have noted that it goes through a couple of changes.  As an example, a link similar to this is presented to the user as the Shared Link:
*https://a360.co/2Xyz6Kb*
*(not a real link - just an example)*

And if you plug that into a browser, it first changes momentarily to something similar to this:
*https://myxyz4.autodesk360.com/g/shares/SH56a43QTfd62c1cd968b6b8eedb8c9de08a*
*(not a real link - just an example)*

And then that eventually resolves into this:
*https://myxyz4.autodesk360.com/g/projects/20200728319292106/data/dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5mb2xkZXI6Y28uYlJ1RjFMZ2RTRktKYXlJZjdqRnNaUQ/dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpkbS5saW5lYWdlOlRhcUJhRjM1VDdTcFl6YUxXbXNiNXc?show=viewer&redirectSource=shared*
*(not a real link - just an example)*

**Is there a way to leverage the information we have access to in order to construct those sorts of Shared Links?**

Comment: I've found another inquiry about this from 3 years ago.  The response at the time was that there was no API access to the shared link mechanism.  However, perhaps that has changed since 2017, so I hope someone 'in the know' still takes a moment to answer.  Thanks!

(Here's the post from 3 years ago...)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974360/autodesk-forge-data-management-api-get-share-link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that functionality is still not exposed, though it is being considered for the future.

Currently, you would need to create your own website that would take care of making the model publicly available. E.g. something like this:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/auto-publish-models-website